# Parsing an English to Math expression question, is this ambiguous?

Tags: mathematics, syntactic-analysis

I'm an instructor of a College Algebra course.  The computer gave the following question,  which I saw as ambiguous:

Computer question: Write the corresponding algebraic expression or equation for the verbal statement. Let x represent the unknown number. The quotient of one and five times a number.

The problem is where does one put in the pause in the English language. You could parse this as either "The quotient of one and five" "times a number" which gives you the answer of 1/5 * x, or the way the computer wants, "The quotient of one and" "five times a number", which gives 1/(5x). The computer only accepts the second interpretation, but according to my reading of the English language, either reading should be acceptable.

Now,  someone else in a comment section noted an even third possible reading, that the times could modify both the 1 and the 5,  giving (1x)/(5x)=1/5 as a third possible reading.

Does anyone have any reasoning/sources on if these are all valid interpretations, and if not,  why one is more valid?  Otherwise I'm going to contact our vendor and try to get this question removed/changed.

Comment: It's gibberish to me.

Comment: It's complete nonsense and completely ambiguous! "The quotient of one and five times a number." is not even a proper sentence (there is no verb) and it's not clear what it's referring to.

Comment: @TrevorD Well, it didn't claim to be a sentence, just a statement.  But yeah, the problem to me is the lack of clarity in the reference,  just wanted to double check with a few random strangers on the internet before I take up the battle with a major educational software vendor!

Comment: But a "statement" still needs to be in the form of a sentence!  If it had a verb in it, it *might* make more sense.

Comment: It's terrible. The 'question' defines the variable x as the unknown number and then doesn't use the defined variable. It would be marginally better if it said "Let x represent the unknown number then express the quotient of one and five times that number." However the best way to express what the computer accepts would be "...then express the reciprocal of five times that number". That would avoid the jump cut at the end of the definition and remove the cause of the ambiguity. Best of luck when arguing with the software vendor!

Comment: The expression is literally 1/5*x. This introduces the main source of ambiguity. If you apply good 'ol BIMDAS, you'd apply the multiplication operator before division, giving you 1/(5x). Use BODMAS, and you get x/5.

Comment: Well, on the logic that "four and twenty" = 4+20 = 24, "one and five" is clearly equal to 6. As a native BrE speaker "quotient" isn't a familiar word to me, but my googling has only led to examples of the form "A divided by B gives the quotient C"; "the quotient of A and B" would therefore appear to be meaningless gobblydegook on its own, let alone including the ambiguity of what the "times" refers to.

Comment: @AndyT, "one and five" could also be 17 pence in the right context (pre-decimal British currency).

Comment: @BoldBen I don't see that "the reciprocal of five times that number" removes the cause of the ambiguity. There's still ambiguity between "(the reciprocal of five) times that number" and "the reciprocal of (five times that number)".

Comment: @AndreasBlass because the simplest way to express (1/5)x would be "that number divided by five".

Comment: This is a good question to ask; it highlights the inconsistencies one often sees in mathematics.

Comment: The appropriate language for mathematical questions is mathematics.

Comment: @TrevorD : You were warned in advance that it could be an "expression", which would normally be a noun rather than a sentence, that was to be translated into mathematical notation. It is crystal-clear that it meant either 1/(5x) or (1/5)x, and it's pretty strongly indicated that it meant the former. It's plainly not gibberish even if it is clumsily expressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely ambiguous, and all three readings you mentioned are possible. I would contact the vendor. But as I'm a computer scientist and native English speaker, below I've given my opinion on what the problem should have said for each equation you listed.

- "(1/5) * x", I would expect to read "The *product* of *one-fifth* and a number."
- "1/(5x)", I would expect to read exactly what the problem states, "The quotient of one and five times a number."
- "(1x)/(5x)", I would expect an even more ambiguous sentence: "The quotient of one times a number and five times a number."

Comment: (1/5)x is not the quotient of one-fifth and a number, but the product of one-fifth and a number.

Comment: Whoops. You're right, that's what I meant to say. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Is (1x)/(5x) not merely 1/5 or 0.2?

Comment: I disagree with the second bullet: the computer question should read, "The quotient of one and the product of five and a number." This makes it clear the quotient is between one and some product, where the product is given by five multiplied by some number.

Answer (score 1):

As alasher says, the statement as it stands is ambiguous and there are all those possible readings.  Since you mentioned pauses, curiously the ambiguities can all be resolved by indicating the pause(s) with one or more commas:

1. The quotient of one, and five times a number (must mean 1/(5x))
2. The quotient of one and five, times a number (must mean 1/5 * x, or x/5)
3. The quotient of one, and five, times a number (must mean x/5x)

That said, I dislike 3 and feel it would be argued by anyone who didn't write down the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this in Mathematics StackExchange meta ([here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30149/13130)) and joined this group to point out a simple fix for the ambiguity in "The quotient of one and five times a number". First, I see two types of [structural ambiguity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22structural+ambiguity%22+linguistics) -- the scope of the second conjunct of "and" (or equivalently in this situation, the scope of the first factor associated with "times"), and the use of "and" for a non-commutative operation (namely, division). The least invasive fix I can think of is the following:

*the quotient of one by five times a number*

Of course this doesn't answer the question asked, and as a nod towards that I recommend contacting the vendor with your concerns, which you said you're considering.

Second, the issue with this not being a complete sentence seems to be a non-issue to me, at least if the phrase to be mathematically translated is not presented as such, because the mathematical equivalent is an expression and not a mathematical statement.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical answer is that according to the order of operations, division and multiplication have the same precedence, and when you have operations with the same precedence, they are taken left to right. So it would be "divide one by five, and then multiply the result by x", or (1/5)x.

The common language answer is that if someone wanted to say "(1/5)x", the natural way of doing so would be to say "one fifth of a number", so the fact that they are not doing so implies that they mean 1/(5x).

BTW, it could be made unambiguous by writing it as "The quotient of one and the product of five times a number" or "The quotient of one and the quantity five times a number" for 1/(5x) or "The product of the quotient of one and five times a number" for (1/5)x